# SugarCRM Field Calculation example of ifElse

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am new to SugarCRM. I have a requirement to calculate a field value through studio. But, in one of the fields which comes in denominator can be 0. So, i want to modify the formula through ifElse, how to do that.

Example - If (field1>0){calcField/field1} else(calcField=0).

Answer (score 1):

you can use calculated field , if else like this:

```
ifElse(equal($status,"Held"),1,0)
```

For more information check this link :

[Calculated field in sugarcrm](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Studio_and_Module_Builder/Sugar_Logic/Capturing_Records_Activities_Counts_Using_Calculated_Fields/)